# Detect moving object over another game object

Tags: unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop, unityscript

I'm new unity user, I want to make board game. This game need to move the game object to (optional) more than one place in the board. And it's need to detect when the movement is allowed or not according to the board state. (It's very similar to nine men morris game).

I try to write code to detect On-Mouse-Up/Down but I find it very complicate. Is there another idea to do that??

Answer (score 0):

Suggest this as an advice because i'm not sure what you're aiming, but
I guess you should create a grid at first and then use pathfinding method to check if you object can move to that place. 
Some of that may be useful: https://tbswithunity3d.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on how doe your game work but general solutions would be:

Store the state of all fields of your board in some array, and when object moves to nowe field you can chack if this field is free.

Or:

When your object moves to new field you can check for collisions with object already in this field.

Comment: the first solution will depend on the position,and making acode depend in position will make it not stable ,any movement in the board position will give wrong detection


the second solution : Is what I asked about ,how to check  where is the  first place of the game object and where it moved ???assuming that there is a collision detection